# Adding to many-to-many collection without querying the main entities

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a batch work, I need to add new relations between existing entities, the entities have big data, I can't get the entities and add them, I have tried this:

```
  for .........
                Class Class = new Class() { ClassID = myClassId };
                context.AddToClasses(Class);
                Student std = new Student() { Id = myStdId };
                context.AddToStudents(std);
                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Class, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(std, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
                Class.ClassStudents.Add(std);

  .............
```

The first call will success, but the second one will give me this exception:

> AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict
>   with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key
>   values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

Tried :

```
  for .........
                Class Class = new Class() { ClassID = myClassId };
                context.Attach(Class);
                Student std = new Student() { Id = myStdId };
                context.Attach(std);
                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(Class, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(std, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
                Class.ClassStudents.Add(std);

  .............
```

Exception:

> An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object
>   context.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are `Class.ClassID` and `Student.Id` the primary key properties? At which line exactly do you get the second exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pairs of `myClassId` and `myStdId` can be repetitive and in no particular order in the loop you are running over this code I would use two dictionaries to hold the already created and attached entities to avoid that you create and attach an entity with the same key a second time, like so:

```
var classDict = new Dictionary<int, Class>();
var studentDict = new Dictionary<int, Student>();

// for ... loop starts here

Class Class;
if (!classDict.TryGetValue(myClassId, out Class))
{
    Class Class = new Class() { ClassID = myClassId };
    context.Classes.Attach(Class);
    classDict.Add(myClassId, Class);
}

Student std;
if (!studentDict.TryGetValue(myStdId, out std))
{
    Student std = new Student() { Id = myStdId };
    context.Students.Attach(std);
    classDict.Add(myStdId, std);
}

Class.ClassStudents.Add(std);

// loop ends here

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Updated my question, Attach will give me a problem!

Comment: Your answer is the best answer when you use .AddToXXX() method instead of .Attach()